# How to Subscribe Multiple topic and Multiple MqttCallback Using PAHO on Java

Tags: java, mqtt

```
static String[] meandgroup = new String[]{"timentask/c/u000000000005", "timentask/c/u0000000GRP85", "timentask/c/u000000GRP107", "timentask/c/u0000000GRP84", "timentask/c/u000000GRP100"};
    public static List<MqttClient> mqttConnect(Object topicId) {
        try {
            mqttClient = new ArrayList<MqttClient>();
            for (int i = 0; i < meandgroup.length; i++) {
                //if (mqttClient.get(i) == null || !mqttClient.get(i).isConnected()){
                if (!globalData.GlobalDataSetGet.MQTT_SERVER_HOST_NAME.equals("") && !globalData.GlobalDataSetGet.MQTT_SERVER_USER_NAME.equals("")) {
                    String topicName = meandgroup[i];
                    mqttClient.add(MqttMgr.subscriber(globalData.GlobalDataSetGet.MQTT_SERVER_HOST_NAME,
                            globalData.GlobalDataSetGet.MQTT_SERVER_PORT_NUMBER, globalData.GlobalDataSetGet.MQTT_SERVER_USER_NAME,
                            globalData.GlobalDataSetGet.MQTT_SERVER_USER_PASSWORD, Constants.MQTT_CONNECTION_KEEP_ALIVE_SECS, topicName, "client" + globalData.GlobalDataSetGet.getUserIdValue, new ChatPaneWrite()));
                }
            }
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mqttClient;
    }
```

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you are trying to do and what is not working

Comment: How to Subscribe Multiple topic and Multiple MqttCallback Using PAHO on Java

Comment: Amazon MQTT cloud server have n number of topic, I trying stay connect/subscribe with dynamic 5 topic and callback to me. who publish this 5 respective topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MQTT allows you to subscribe any topic wildcardly. This means, you dont need to actully subscribe all topics.
`"timentask/c/u000000000005", "timentask/c/u0000000GRP85"`
Instead, subscribe to `"timentask/c/#"`

Comment: If I do that, I got all incoming publish message from mqtt chat server!!!!!!. Understand my ? answer try it, do timentask/c/a/u000000000005 to timentask/c/z/u000000000005 but i need only timentask/c/a/u000000000005,timentask/c/b/u000000000005 and timentask/c/c/u000000000005 only these three

Comment: Amazon MQTT cloud server have n number of topic, I trying stay connect/subscribe with dynamic 5 topic and callback to me. who publish this 5 respective topic.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you're trying to create a new MQTT client for each subscription, this is likely very unnecessary for most applications. You might be better off just using one client and then subscribe using a topic array (As described here:     [subscribe(String[] topicFilters, int[] qos)](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttAsyncClient.html#subscribe(java.lang.String[],%20int[])))
e.g.

```
mqttAsyncClient.subscribe(["/topic1", "/topic2", "/topic3"], [0,1,2]);
```

When any messages are delivered to your MqttCallback, then the topic that the message was published to will also be provided, so you'll still be able to tell where the message came from and be able to route it accordingly.

Comment: MqttException (0) - Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException
 at mqttconfig.MqttMgr.getMqttClient(MqttMgr.java:91)
 at mqttconfig.MqttMgr.subscriber(MqttMgr.java:35)
 at mqttconfig.MqttUtil.mqttConnect(MqttUtil.java:38)
 at LogIn$49$4.doInBackground(LogIn.java:2003)
 at LogIn$49$4.doInBackground(LogIn.java:1999)